# TLS issue with go get

Tags: go

I'm trying to install etcctl from github. (P.S I don't know golang)

`git config --global http.sslVerify false
go get github.com/coreos/etcd/etcdctl`

But I'm hitting the following.

`github.com/coreos/etcd/vendor/go.uber.org/zap
/root/projects/src/src/github.com/coreos/etcd/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/field.go:33: syntax error: unexpected = in type declaration
github.com/coreos/etcd/pkg/tlsutil
/root/projects/src/src/github.com/coreos/etcd/pkg/tlsutil/cipher_suites.go:26: undefined: tls.TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
/root/projects/src/src/github.com/coreos/etcd/pkg/tlsutil/cipher_suites.go:36: undefined: tls.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
/root/projects/src/src/github.com/coreos/etcd/pkg/tlsutil/cipher_suites.go:37: undefined: tls.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
/root/projects/src/src/github.com/coreos/etcd/pkg/tlsutil/cipher_suites.go:42: undefined: tls.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305
/root/projects/src/src/github.com/coreos/etcd/pkg/tlsutil/cipher_suites.go:43: undefined: tls.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305`

Comment: Use a Go version which support type aliases. Your version is outdated. This is a compile error and not related to go get.

Comment: Also: `git config --global http.sslVerify false` is quite dangerous. You should revert that.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use an old version of Go. etcd [requires Go 1.10 or newer](https://github.com/coreos/etcd#getting-etcd) to build.